# Cancel file selection in Formik form (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik form in my React application to create a new post and I have an input field of type "file". The problem I face now is I cannot implement a cancelation of the action. With the code I am proving I do update the form values and the preview image disappears but I still can see the name of the file on the screen which should be "no file chosen" instead. I went through Formik documentation but did not find a solution. Any ideas will help. Thank you.
Setting value={values.image} gives these errors:

> Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import { createPost } from "../actions";
const NewPost = () => {
    
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleImageUpload = async (event, setFieldValue) => {
    // .... some code where I obtain the image URLs
    setFieldValue("image", file.secure_url);
    setFieldValue("largeImage", file.eager[0].secure_url);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ image: "", largeImage: "", title: "", body: "" }}
        validate={(values) => {
          const errors = {};
          //... validation
          return errors;
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          const { title, body, image, largeImage } = values;
          dispatch(
            createPost(
              {
                title,
                body,
                image,
                largeImage,
              },
              history
            )
          );
          setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {({
          values,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          setFieldValue,
          isSubmitting,
          /* and other goodies */
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="new__post-form">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>

              <div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="image">Upload File</label>
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    type="file"
                    name="image"
                    id="image"
                    placeholder="Upload an image"
                    onChange={(e) => handleImageUpload(e, setFieldValue)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  {values.image && (
                    <>
                      <img src={values.image} alt="Upload Preview" />
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setFieldValue("image", "");
                          setFieldValue("largeImage", "");
                        }}
                      >
                        X
                      </button>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewPost;
```